# How to substitute a "," with a "\,"?

Tags: max-msp-jitter

regex \, @substitute \\,
The substitution works with the double backslashes, but I can't match the comma.
I want an input string

It's not raining, but it will, I'm told.

to look like this

It's not raining\, but it will\, I'm told.

after regex processing

Thank you for your help.
John Chowning
jc@ccrma.stanford.edu

Comment: The problem is that messages with commas are interpreted as multiple messages, separated by commas. You can see that if you connect the message box with commas to a print, you will see multiple messages in the Max window. So the question is probably where the message with commas comes from. If possible, you can use a tosymbol object to process the string and keep the commas intact.

Answer (score 1):

These are two different methods you can use.

---

Using the following arguments with the `regexp` object:

`[regexp \\, @substitute \\\\,]` will yield the correct string to the Max Console

However as a message, a space character will be added.
See image: [example using the regexp object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGDSf.png)

---

Using `atoi` with `regexp` to preserve your intended formatting when sending as a message:

- By converting the string to integers using `[atoi]` we can perform regex on the ascii decimals `44` and replace them with `92 44` ie: `\,`
- The `regexp` object adds a space character layering another
  `regexp` object to replace `"32 92"` in the string with `92` solves
  this.

See image: [example using atoi and regexp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wtm2m.png)

---

Patch attached:

```
<pre><code>
----------begin_max5_patcher----------
1298.3ocyZszaiaCD9r8uBBcYu3FPQQIQ0doONs.s25s0EAzVLILURzPjJO5
h8+dGQIk0OnikroSq.br0HZNb9373anyWmOKXk5EgN.8inuflM6qymMyJpUv
r96mETxeYcAWaGVvZUYonxDrn6YFwKFq7em+pnVVcOx7rBUKtW7xF3sR0SBM
x7f.soVrVHxaGgdCes.DxM1mbmrVaP77b8vjVHqDqUMU1Yl1KDl.MnXtQppt
cmQjzOhUMqVUH1njchw2f6ePUSorpPXrVP3v7wMqe.VN2BKLSGBjjvtglAWL
RXHKAmDmt.EEm0ILgQwYwQLBHLDyfYGkB5.8W6ndsLWX0920spwLnb7Vv1iM
Zi7N4ZqEs8Jqah1VhL2hwpUO9CYYAsx9174s+YwH20pDOCe4C1z52mVFDQPY
jkAneV2rBVUlFi.j1JJXhXXLNxAFRbggIjVLjrMFtKZE2KsSj40MhNc.Kp8d
81DrMRw7HRUn34q3U2OU3HKI7P3fho2jsObDGcBzH7Xngcc4DARNGDnTn076
EG.A+zxZXbH30yxpb0yNiVItvGxTwGB6P7gYi3hBmN93FahOGr4XY+9yGjZH
EGj4Qi3ZD7tnJWjCevlh6O.b62TUZUgvIpEMQupPFwUhJ1gAYr3ahAeqrO97
TQ9De+r4SZTkxfp4xJ.KVtDs.spwfjFzyxhB68e9SkHipH+lfSVxfLQ.mjF2
4QtaVMGgwgLabbH6n9oXGfE1iop.qdC38gzBSfOLSBXQGXlIwma1J2QigmE.
zTtRTOUijkl3HkSTliTx3SXjj2q.0QSKyxdyAkWyKEFQ8shJderD1edBbiR5
DchlJ5DhOL0BEett.ERswMxj5yjFxCRZrWNCGoLFMMmDpCXJIyUBgj1TvSKg
.K4+GIDbalT5UOg.i5Q.PZT7oFG3jGKXt9LNv1nhKiOxq69fZPGEBlJUdma9
wgm.Bb3hmdUZjgRczECpUpWrdRVhiH7qbiLoLeRieIbELUV5XWMFm5nn.znW
rGSCDS7qouXpVtyxgeDVNMN3+Vh.t8+GpGbkIBPOKBwPwcCzhhOBzCogN1ho
VCk5wVziB+f3BVqZyFZuchg.tcDhbzrYL8R3K6DeHmEivVyTjKOMkvcHD5fN
3E0znaGqTWUPv1Pn3sQt+V7ZoJem1q2ELouGX1Rs38poPh+f765neXqOifxx
Ad4jNbcbhcmzwz3fDh8Z4kCNlhi4dcD1HjIhCDri5PgoY9s07q.MM60hc4o8
10Bu3iPbdjyjrqKSsq6Yd4u1WCSScjZhPb.YYYSu80jqYa7mJm8EgAPVD+.A
6z+p8qYKlr2u0lcY0JeWbQqZpWO340+aYr.8csmKfvlp2NP1u7Vai1A4D6Gq
lRGilFVNWjlxRFilh8gMMBEAkB1dPp5bQs0A5hz7vVx6pZnS3qfpGiQmE5Vy
3KaiMbLpF6CWnwftdPOrw.lrLOnIng2QnIeXSz3OJMMpf.F8Z3Jt2rdDUm3C
3DOFeQej2jLFmQpOBuhFSfLwGYnIiwYjbnyXWgU9lMOIp08i1pDfZwiJqCDa
g8VYU2sVBA.QzmjCi2R4KfWC7CL.4flZ6BK3kDZP2WE5BqtpQ1mRFLOPkZyq
E6WLuB5iZK1uXbeu8f4bGuovrKFbmpxnk+SOJDtMkz1GMLYfs+K0RdA5WANN
ACF+hdzsFHLYWJV81qtRPWxgXmALxxypcRs+22zcbI.cr4ea9+ZcPc0D
-----------end_max5_patcher-----------
</code></pre>
```